# PThread Mutex Lock & Unlock on Stack

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     2

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

char **AddToStack(char *buffer)
{
  static char **stack = NULL;
  int stacksize = 0;

  if (buffer == NULL)
    return stack;

  if (stack == NULL){
    stack = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
  }
  stack[stacksize] = strdup(buffer);
  stacksize++;
  stack = realloc(stack, (stacksize+1) * sizeof(char*));
  stack[stacksize] = NULL;
  return stack;
}

void *FRead(void *threadid)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  char fname[256], buffer[256];
  FILE *ifile;
  long tid;
  int counter;
  tid = (long)threadid;

  sprintf(fname, "data%ld", tid);
  if ((ifile = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Error: Thread #%ld was unable to open file %s!\n", tid, fname);
  }
  else{
    printf("Thread #%ld starting to read from file %s!\n", tid, fname);
    fscanf(ifile, "%s", buffer);
    counter = 0;
 while (!feof(ifile)){
//pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    counter++;
      AddToStack(buffer);
      fscanf(ifile, "%s", buffer);
//pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    fclose(ifile);
    printf("Thread #%ld added %d entries to the stack!\n", tid, counter);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc, i = 0;
  long t;
  char **stack;
  FILE *ofile;

  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, FRead, (void *)t);
    if (rc){
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }


for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
{
//pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
}


  //Lets write the content of the stack into a file
  stack = AddToStack(NULL); //Get the base of the stack pointer
  if (stack != NULL){
    ofile = fopen("result.dat", "w");
    for (i = 0; stack[i] != NULL; i++)
      fprintf(ofile, "%s\n", stack[i]);
    fclose(ofile);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "%d data written to file result.dat\n", i);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my data1 and data2 files

data1:
    abandons
    abase
    abased
    abases
    abash
    abashed
    abashes
    abashing
    abasing
    abate
    abated
    abatement
    abates
    abating
    abattoir
    abbey
    abbort
    abbreviate
    abbreviated
    abbreviates
    abbreviating
    abbreviation
    abbreviations
    abdicate
    abdicated
    abdicates
    abdicating
    abdomen
    abduct
    abducted

data2 :

```
God
I
I'll
I'm
I've
Miss
Worry
a
ability
able
aboard
about
above
abroad
absence
absent
absolute
accident
accidentally
according
accordingly
account
acquaintance
across
act
action
active
activity
actual
admiration
admission
adress
advance
advantage
adventure
```

Above is my mutex code, but i wonder why i only can write 1 data to the file result.dat

This is my output

1 data written to file result.dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);pthread_exit(NULL);` location is incorrect. Place this before `return NULL` statement.

There were couple of errors in the code. Please find below the updated code.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     2

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

char **AddToStack(char *buffer)
{
  static char **stack = NULL;
  static int stacksize = 0;

  if (buffer == NULL)
    return stack;

  if (stack == NULL){
    stack = (char**)calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
  }
  stack[stacksize] = strdup(buffer);
  stacksize++;
  stack = (char**)realloc(stack, (stacksize+1) * sizeof(char*));
  stack[stacksize] = NULL;
  return stack;
}

void *FRead(void *threadid)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  char fname[256], buffer[256];
  FILE *ifile;
  long tid;
  int counter;
  tid = (long)threadid;

  sprintf(fname, "data%ld", tid);
  if ((ifile = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Error: Thread #%ld was unable to open file %s!\n", tid, fname);
  }
  else{
    printf("Thread #%ld starting to read from file %s!\n", tid, fname);
    fscanf(ifile, "%s", buffer);
    counter = 0;
    while (!feof(ifile)){
      //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
      counter++;
      AddToStack(buffer);
      fscanf(ifile, "%s", buffer);
      //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    fclose(ifile);
    printf("Thread #%ld added %d entries to the stack!\n", tid, counter);
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc, i = 0;
  long t;
  char **stack;
  FILE *ofile;

  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, FRead, (void *)t);
    if (rc){
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }


  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
  {
    //pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
  }


  //Lets write the content of the stack into a file
  stack = AddToStack(NULL); //Get the base of the stack pointer
  if (stack != NULL){
    ofile = fopen("result.dat", "w");
    for (i = 0; stack[i] != NULL; i++)
      fprintf(ofile, "%s\n", stack[i]);
    fclose(ofile);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "%d data written to file result.dat\n", i);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it doesn't work. 0 data written to file result.dat

Comment: that is because stacksize is local variable. That means all values will always get overwritten on zeroth index. I have changed the code.